# wordpress class 'current-menu-item' not showing in nav menu in some pages when we are on the current page

Tags: wordpress

I am working on the wordpress. I have created Footer Menu in admin panel and I want to show it on my site footer. I have used the function below. Problem is that the class 'current-menu-item' not appearing on some pages when we are on the current page to show active menu item  selected. can I make it selected ?

```
    <?php
      $defaults = array(
        'menu'            => 'Footer Menu'

         );

      wp_nav_menu( $defaults ); ?>
```

Comment: can you please provide html page source for your header/footer, if you can provide structure, it will easy for us to provide solution?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery solwing these problem :
Please write these jQuery script and check

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){

  var activeurl = window.location;
  if(jQuery('a[href="'+activeurl+'"]').parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().hasClass('menuitem'))
  {
     jQuery('a[href="'+activeurl+'"]').parent().parent().parent().children('h3').children('a').addClass('current-menu-item');
     jQuery('a[href="'+activeurl+'"]').parent().parent().addClass('current-menu-item');
  }
  else
  {
     jQuery('a[href="'+activeurl+'"]').parent().parent().parent().children('a').addClass('current-menu-item');
     jQuery('a[href="'+activeurl+'"]').addClass('current-menu-item');
     jQuery('a[href="'+activeurl+'"]').parent().parent().addClass('current-menu-item');
  }


});
</script>
```

Comment: Please format this code correctly. Use the editor to indent it.